# Zabbix server and agent using dns with docker swarm 1.12- connection problems

Tags: docker, dns, zabbix

I have a connection problem with Zabbix when i'm using docker swarm.
Some info:

- I have a Zabbix server and Zabbix  agent (both docker containers).
- I am using docker swarm (docker 1.12) for the deployment.
- I created a private network with docker called `mynetwork`

**Zabbix server deploy commands:**

```
docker service create -name zabbix-server-dns...--network=mynetwork...-p some-ports...zabbix-server-image
```

in the Zabbix server conf: `sourceIP=0.0.0.0`
Zabbix agent deploy commands:

```
docker service create -name zabbix-agent-dns...--network=mynetwork...-e server=zabbix-server-dns...-p some-ports...zabbix-agent-image
```

**in Zabbix ui:**
I created host name: `zabbix-agent-dns`. I put the same name in the dns and port 10050 and attach template. The host turned green in the ui, but not monitoring! All I get is item unsupport. I manage to ping from inside Zabbix server container to the agent container but not from agent container to server. I think the Zabbix server managed to send the agent the item request, the agent managed to get the request and process it, but something is wrong when it tries to send the data back to Zabbix server and I don't know why.

Help please...

I must say that if I run the same containers without docker swarm and my new network it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your item keys are wrong. You did not mention which template you linked or what item keys it had, but in any case test the keys with `zabbix_get` and fix any that are reported as "unsupported".

Comment: The problem is not with my item keys, because when i am running the same without using the network "mynetwork" it's working fine (i get the correct value from zabbix_get).

Comment: What is the exact error message? What is the configuration of that item?

Answer (score 0):

The probleme solved. In Docker 1.12 (swarm mode), the VM ip is not recognized as the real ip, so when i created a host in zabbix ui with the configurations: "my-vm-ip" "my-agent-port" the agent did not get the request from "my-vm-ip", it get it from docker swarm ingress network, so we need to allow connections from it as well. You need to deploy the agent with:
-e server="docker-swarm-ingress-network-ip"...